# How to know the x,y positions of my mouse when I drag around a mapView in the Android emulator?

Tags: android

All I achieve now is using onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) event to get the first touch.

But I want to know the x,y values when I continuously drag the mapView.

If anyone knows the answer it would be greatly
appreciated.

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126907/how-to-get-the-pointer-cursor-location-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its pretty straight forward. Here is some code that returns an x & y position of a touch and then returns an angle to rotate an image based on the touch position.

```
//TouchEvent handler
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onTouchEvent called...");
    x = event.getX();
    y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

        float dx = x - mPreviousX;
        float dy = y - mPreviousY;

        //Reverse direction of rotation if above midline
        if (y > getHeight() / 2) {
            dx = dx * -1;
        }

        //Reverse direction of rotation if of the midline
        if (y < getWidth() / 2) {
            dy = dy * -1;
        }

        Main.mAngle += (dx + dy) * TOUCH_SCALE_FACTOR;

        TextView txtView = (TextView) ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.mangle);
        txtView.setText("Angle: " + String.valueOf(Main.mAngle));

        requestRender();
    }

    mPreviousX = x;
    mPreviousY = y;

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

MotionEvent ACTION_MOVE

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_MOVE

[Tutorial showing how to use it](https://web.archive.org/web/20201026064852/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/06/drawing-with-canvas-in-android.html)