# How to show X/Y lines as in the Pointer Location developer option

Tags: android

As shown in this link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1KIX.png (I don't have enough rep to directly post images)

My app currently loads a Bitmap into a Canvas and draws it to an ImageView.

I'm trying to record some pixel locations and I want the last touched spot to show the two lines intersecting at its location. I don't need the rest of the data shown in pointer location.

Edit: To be clear, I want the app to have this in its functionality without using the developer option.

Comment: It might help to show some code as to what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be under Settings -> Developer options -> Pointer location

EDIT: See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126907/how-to-get-the-pointer-cursor-location-in-android).

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. I want the app to do this itself without using the developer option.